# AS3 UrlLoader does not fire Event.COMPLETE

Tags: actionscript-3, http, flash

Everything work, except the Event.Complete... (that means that I retrieve the good content at the server side, and the progress event work as expected)

I have a simple code that process an upload. I use this class : https://github.com/Nek-/Multipart.as/blob/master/src/com/jonas/net/Multipart.as

And my code:

```
package com.foo.http 
{
    import com.jonas.net.Multipart;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

    public class RequestManager
    {
        private var request:Multipart;
        private var loader:URLLoader;

        /**
         * The url can be http://foobar:952/helloworld
         * @param   url
         */
        public function RequestManager(url:String)
        {
            this.loader = new URLLoader();
            this.request = new Multipart(url);

            // This is needed, if we don't set it, the complete event will never be trigger
            // We retrieve some text
            this.loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

            // Events
            this.attachEvents();
        }

        public function getRequest():Multipart
        {
            return this.request;
        }

        public function send():void
        {
            this.loader.load(this.request.request);
        }

        private function attachEvents():void
        {
            this.loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.requestCompleted);
            this.loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, this.requestProgress);
            this.loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, this.securityError);
            this.loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, this.networkError);
        }

        // Of course there is also listener methods (with a trace inside and call to JS, nothing more)
    }
}
```

Any idea what it comes from ?

Comment: are you missing listener functions in `RequestManager`? I dont see `requestCompleted` and others in your class?

Comment: They exists and are quite simple. I didn't put them because it's useless.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like my problem was not from actionscript or flash itself but from my javascript and the flash debugger on firefox.

Comment: glad that you found the problem